# What is the suitable storage for mobile application?

Tags: javascript, database, mobile, storage

I am currently developing a mobile app using `React native`. It uses the JavaScript language.

My app is mainly designed to store `PDF` documents that users upload and I want to choose the correct database to store the documents.

Which back-end storage will suit my app. Is using Firebase already ok?

Comment: forget react native - use native script.https://www.nativescript.org

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is very general, whereas this site is best suited to solve coding problems. I suggest research this topic first and then for sure ask questions about any coding problems you have with your chosen back-end database.